# SSH timeout issues not consistent

Tags: ssh, centos6, ssh-keys

I am not sure if anyone else have had issues with SSH timeout

I setup a FRESH install of CentOS 6.5 minimal without touching the SSH congfig at all and when i log into it via SSH using putty..it NEVER times out. I can have it on for weeks and it won't timeout even when idle

I setup another fresh insatll and wihtout touching the ssh config, it times out every like 2 minutes or so

I mean why is this so? Is SSH timeout like a coin toss, it may timeout more often for some servers than others even with same exact config? Anyone else experienced this?

Anyways i went ahead and add

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

on the server and still get timeout issues

Can someone please tell me how to have a CONSISTENT ssh config that will disable timeout completely..that will work 100% of the time like it is expected to be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Connection timeouts are most often caused by packet filter or NAT device timing out your TCP connection due to inactivity. There is no one golden rule regarding ssh settings. Much depends on your systems and connections. Generally you should set keep-alive interval value to less than it usually takes for your connection to time out (be kicked off from the connections table in your system).

You may set it on server as `ClientAliveInterval` or on client as `ServerAliveInterval`. The value is number of seconds. If you set it to too high value ssh may not be able to send the message before the connection is dropped.

You should also increase maximum number of keep-alive retries on server (`ClientAliveCountMax`) or client (`ServerAliveCountMax`). Default value is 3.

This count means how many times server/client will try to get keep-alive acknowledgment from the other side before disconnecting. Let's say you set `ClientAliveInterval` to 60 seconds and `ClientAliveCountMax` to 10. The connection will be dropped after 10 tries * 60 seconds if one of the parties will not respond to 10 consecutive keep-alive queries. You may try to increase this parameter to much higher level, like 100 or even 9999 (?).

You may also consider turning off TCP keep-alive packets on both client and server.

```
TCPKeepAlive no
```

This means that connections will not die if the route goes down temporarily. But on the other hand the connections may sometimes hang (especially if you set `AliveCountMax` to high value) if there is communication problem, because the problem will not be detected by ssh at TCP level.

See also:

- [OpenSSH FAQ](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#2.12)
- [SSH client config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5)
- [SSH server config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5)

Comment: Your answer seem to imply that timeouts could sometimes be caused by ssh settings. As far as I know both client and server will permit an idle ssh connection to stay alive indefinitely (unless the client never presented any valid credentials in the first place). Once you have logged in the only reasons I know for an idle connection to time out would be a networking problem (with NAT being one of the most often seen networking problems) or one of the endpoints being rebooted.

Comment: @kasperd You are right. SSH settings define how long the session will survive some temporary network problems. I rephrased my answer.